# Apple Music doesn't display song's lyrics from MP3 ID3 tag

Tags: iphone, ios, music, apple-music, mp3

How can I display lyrics on Apple Music?

**Here's my steps:**

1. I edit MP3 tags through [kid3](https://kid3.sourceforge.io/) app.
2. I add lyrics to my MP3 file into the Tag 2 ID3v2.3.0 with encoding ISO-8859-1 (I've also tried UTF-8 and UTF-16):

   [image: Tag 2: ID3v2.3.0]
3. I save my MP3 file and send to my iPhone (iOS 11.4);

**What I expect as a result:** lyrics are displayed in music app.

**What I actually get:** no lyrics displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I use kid3 to add lyrics to mp3 files, which the iOS Music app can then show. I can take you through how I do it with macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 and iOS 11.4.

The information you have supplied looks correct. Like your example, I use kid3 to write Tag 2:ID3v2.3.0

[image]

The text encoding I use is ISO-8859-1 (which I understand is basically ASCII, is compatible with UTF8, and is fine unless you have non ascii characters in your lyrics). 
Furthermore `Language` is set to `eng`.

[image]

Having saved the lyrics into the file with kid3,  check in iTunes if your song contains your lyrics. 
Right click on the track in iTunes, select `Song Info`, and select the `Lyrics` tab. The lyrics you added in kid3 should be visible, and the `Custom Lyrics` box in the bottom left hand corner should be checked.
If the lyrics are not present then delete the song/album from the iTunes library, re-import it, and check the lyrics are visible in iTunes before proceeding.

[image]

Next delete the song/album on your iPhone. Then transfer across the new copy from iTunes to your iPhone.

On your iPhone bring up the album containing your song:-

[image]

Tap and **hold** on the track name until a menu appears, then swipe up to show the bottom of the menu list - `Lyrics` is often right at the bottom and can even be partially or fully hidden when the menu first appears.

[image]

The lyrics should then be visible:-

[image]

Having said all this, I personally find viewing lyrics from mp3s with the Apple iOS Music app to be extremely poorly designed, and much prefer to use other 3rd party apps such as [Cesium](http://www.cesium-app.com).