# Can I add lyrics to songs and have them synced with the song?

Tags: itunes, apple-music, music.app, lyrics

As of now, I can just copy paste raw lyrics, which won't sync with the song!

Edit: I'm on Windows 10 Pro, Version 2004, Build 19541.
iTunes is the iTunes64Setup.exe file install, not the Microsoft Store version, version: 12.10.3.1

I've seen [other answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/328286/67264), and tried what they suggested, which worked, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.
See, what I could do right now is, go to a specific song in my song Library, right click it and go to Song Info, then Lyrics, and add Custom Lyrics. This works, and I'm able to view those static, unsynchronized lyrics on my iPhone.

But I wanna see if I can go a step further, **adding *synchronized* lyrics**, see how in some services, Apple Music maybe, or Spotify, the lyrics will auto scroll, or slide to the next line/verse as the song goes on. Similar to how Subtitles work in movies.

So is this something that could be done? Either using iTunes or any other software!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please see [ask] for important info on asking questions.  Your question is missing a lot of info. What version of itunes?  Mac or Windows?  What have you already tried (several answers already on this site)?  You can [edit] your question to add that info.

Comment: @fsb oh hey thank you! I just edited my question!!

Comment: Iʼm looking for information how Apple stores time codes for lyrics, too. I *assume* that they are using a standard subtitle track in the MP4 file (i.e. closed captions), which could be in WebVTT, SRT or ASS/SSA format or, most likely, whatever it is that FFmpeg calls `mov_text`.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/302857/67264

Comment: You would try to add the lyrics as a Timed Text track according to [MPEG-4 Part 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_17), assuming the music is in an MP4 container with `.m4a` file extension.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few variations to cover, including unsynced lyrics for completeness:

- unsynced vs **synchronized** (also called time-synced or "Live Lyrics")
- 3rd-party apps vs **Apple-specific** Music apps, like iTunes
- MP3 files vs **MP4 containers** (M4A is audio-only MP4)

---

### Unsynced lyrics

Unsynced lyrics are fairly easy. You can use the iTunes / Apple Music context menu => "Get Info" and paste in a block of text, which for MP3 files is an ID3 v2.something tag (`USLT`, which you can see in the [eyeD3 Python library](https://github.com/nicfit/eyeD3/blob/5108937485555c81ca992a4def7d74f860ee978d/eyed3/id3/frames.py#L2059) (contrast with `SYLT` for synced lyrics)).

- This [`lrcput.py` script](https://github.com/TheRedSpy15/lrcput/blob/main/lrcput.py) shows how to use the Python libraries "eyed3" for MP3 files, and "mutagen" to embed them into FLAC.
- MP4 containers are handled similarly, the mutagen MP4 API is nearly identical to its FLAC API.

### 3rd-party apps

For a **non-iTunes** app, you can generally download [.lrc files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format)) for synchronized and name them similarly to the audio file, and the apps wil pick them up (see [LRCGET](https://github.com/tranxuanthang/lrcget), which uses https://lrclib.net/ to get lyrics).

---

### Synced lyrics with Apple Music

Testing with various **MP3 files with synchronized lyrics doesn't show any lyrics at all** in Apple Music (source files from [this 2021 blog](https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/embedded-lyrics.htm)). Unsynchronized lyrics show up fine. Ominously, Apple support docs mention that you won't have access to Live Lyrics without an Apple Music subscription.

Now for the original thing I was trying to do, **Apple Music + M4A files**: Apple currently uses Musixmatch to provide synchronized lyrics, which looks like anyone can submit lyrics to. These seem to be provided in [TTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timed_text) format, and are then made available to Apple Music subscribers.

> Technical notes:
>
> To apply synced lyrics to your local M4A files, it looks like you'll need to put them in the iTunes-specific `"\xa9lyr"` field ([mutagen docs](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mp4.html#mutagen.mp4.MP4Tags)), and I think these same field names are used in MP3 ID3 tags, as well.
>
> <s>There exists at least [one GitHub project](https://github.com/dropcreations/Manzana-Apple-Music-Tagger/blob/28fd2d7f50f17bf2f673ca9cef38b79d1bed3140/core/process/tagger.py#L39) that can read content profiles (including TTML data) from Apple Music and somehow embeds it in your audio files.</s> On closer inspection, this project seems to be embedding unsynced lyrics:
>
> 1. `api.api.getInfo()` calls Apple Music, passes the response to…
> 2. `api.parse.parseJson()`, and the data-synced lyrics are in `data["relationships"]["lyrics"]["data"][0]["attributes"]["ttml"]`.
> 3. But when tagging actual files, `core.process.tagger.tag()` seems to be pulling lyrics from `data["streams"][i]["lyrics"]`.

Outright embedding the contents of a full .lrc or .ttml with mutagen doesn't seem to work, though. I would guess that for Apple Music, synchronized lyrics are brought in through some side channel via the Apple Music subscription service.

Comment: Does Apple Music.app on macOS at all support synchronized lyrics embedded in local files (e.g. from amateur recordings)? Or do synchronized lyrics work only by "side channel loading" through the Apple Music subscription service?

Comment: I haven't gotten Apple Music to show any synchronized lyrics at all, esp since I don't have an Apple Music subscription. I think a next step would be finding a file/system where synced lyrics work already, then checking if there's anything embedded in the files.

Comment: I answered this myself meanwhile as a [stand-alone Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/468853/11510): Apple Music as of now only supports synchronized lyrics sideloaded from its Apple Music subscription service. It does not support loading synced lyrics from local files.

Comment: You are right on your approach for further investigation: Get a file from a Mac which uses an Apple Music subscription. 1) Get a song with lyrics. 2) Get offline. Only then activate synced lyrics function. Works? Strong indication that embedded. 3) If not then get online try again. Works?  Proof that only fetched on demand. 4) Go offline. Try again. 5) Quit Music app. Try again. 6) Restart. Try again. 456 test for potential caching or storing aside. 7) Inspect file with hex editor for lyric snippets.

Comment: Also Note: Github project Manzana claims NOT „to embed it [=lyrics] in your audio files“. You linked to a parser function. Not an embedding/writing function. At https://github.com/dropcreations/Manzana-Apple-Music-Tagger/#How-to-use its quoted `—help` output screen says: `-ln, --no-lrc         Don't save time-synced lyrics as a .lrc file. (default: False)` and the fact of a .LRC file is mentioned several times. Found no explicit mention of writing the lyrics to the M4A file!

Comment: Dang. Greatly appreciate the checks and additional detail in your Q&A, I'll update my answer to match.